# Shortcut for dragging a window by any pixel?

Tags: windows

I want to be able to have a shortcut that enables me to drag a window from any pixelposition inside that window as if I was clicking on its titlebar.
In Gnome 3 this is possible with Alt+click, but I want it in Windows too!

Comment: Does `Alt+Space, R`, then use the arrow keys work for you?

Comment: No, I need this functionality for quickly rearranging windows, to look at underlying desktop or other windows.

Comment: Note, after `Alt+Space,M,<Any Arrow Key>`, it will stick to the mouse until you click. Not as nice as `Alt+Click`, but maybe some magic with AutoHotKey can minimize the pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AutoHotKey script or compiled executable from [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/get-the-linux-altwindow-drag-functionality-in-windows/) to do this.

```
; This script modified from the original: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/EasyWindowDrag.htm
; by The How-To Geek
; http://www.howtogeek.com 

Alt & LButton::
CoordMode, Mouse  ; Switch to screen/absolute coordinates.
MouseGetPos, EWD_MouseStartX, EWD_MouseStartY, EWD_MouseWin
WinGetPos, EWD_OriginalPosX, EWD_OriginalPosY,,, ahk_id %EWD_MouseWin%
WinGet, EWD_WinState, MinMax, ahk_id %EWD_MouseWin% 
if EWD_WinState = 0  ; Only if the window isn't maximized 
    SetTimer, EWD_WatchMouse, 10 ; Track the mouse as the user drags it.
return

EWD_WatchMouse:
GetKeyState, EWD_LButtonState, LButton, P
if EWD_LButtonState = U  ; Button has been released, so drag is complete.
{
    SetTimer, EWD_WatchMouse, off
    return
}
GetKeyState, EWD_EscapeState, Escape, P
if EWD_EscapeState = D  ; Escape has been pressed, so drag is cancelled.
{
    SetTimer, EWD_WatchMouse, off
    WinMove, ahk_id %EWD_MouseWin%,, %EWD_OriginalPosX%, %EWD_OriginalPosY%
    return
}
; Otherwise, reposition the window to match the change in mouse coordinates
; caused by the user having dragged the mouse:
CoordMode, Mouse
MouseGetPos, EWD_MouseX, EWD_MouseY
WinGetPos, EWD_WinX, EWD_WinY,,, ahk_id %EWD_MouseWin%
SetWinDelay, -1   ; Makes the below move faster/smoother.
WinMove, ahk_id %EWD_MouseWin%,, EWD_WinX + EWD_MouseX - EWD_MouseStartX, EWD_WinY + EWD_MouseY - EWD_MouseStartY
EWD_MouseStartX := EWD_MouseX  ; Update for the next timer-call to this subroutine.
EWD_MouseStartY := EWD_MouseY
return
```

Comment: that answers my question, although it doesn't behave exactly like a drag, because if you drag your window to the sides, it doesn't offer to snap/maximize to the halfside of the display.